Transcendentality of $\log_{\frac{p}{q}} \log_{\frac{p}{q}} 2$
I was working on proof questions (not much of relevant context...) regarding irrationality and transcendence, and I was wondering whether, given some $1<\frac{p}{q}<2$, that
$$\log_{\frac{p}{q}} \log_{\frac{p}{q}} 2 = \left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^{k\cdot\frac{p}{q}}$$
is possible, where $k$, $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ are all integers? (I, by the way, am trying to show that this does not work).
I figured out that, given the Gelfond–Schneider theorem, $\log_{\frac{p}{q}}2$ would definitely be transcendental, and $\log_{\frac{p}{q}} \log_{\frac{p}{q}} 2$ would highly likely be transcendental too, but could be algebraic-irrational. If $\log_{\frac{p}{q}} \log_{\frac{p}{q}} 2$ then problem solved - the equation above cannot suffice, but in the case of being algebraic-irrational, could the equation above work? Or even in that case is it still not possible?

The current state of the art does not allow us to determine $\log_{p/q}(\log_{p/q}(2))$ is transcendental. We can, however, show that $\log_{p/q} (\log_{p/q}(2))$ is irrational!
By way of contradiction write
$$\log_{\frac{p}{q}} \log_{\frac{p}{q}} 2 = a/b$$
And we can rewrite
$$(p/q)^{a/b}=\log_{p/q}(2)$$
But now the lefthand side is algebraic and the righthand side is transcendental so we have shown that these two sides cannot be equal.

I cannot quite rule your equation as never true [without Schanuel's Conjecture] but when $q$ divides $k$ the righthand side is rational. So we can conclude that $q$ cannot divide $k$.

This answer could be improved... If we take Schanuels Conjecture we should be able to prove the number transcendental but somehow the proof is taking me longer than I expected.

I will either get to it but you (the OP) or anyone could try it on.
